# Eu preciso utilizar apenas o wp_posts de outro db WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu tenho 2 sites com temas diferentes em *WordPress*:

Site 01: `MAIN`

Site 02: `Secundario`

**(Preciso que o site 02 acesse o banco de dados do site 01 e pegue os posts de lá sempre)**

Não sei como fazer isso, alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

A menos que vc tenha uma ótima justificativa pra carregar o BD diretamente, use a [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) nativa do WordPress:

Por exemplo:

```
GET https://site01.teste/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

ou

```
$posts = wp_remote_get( 'https://site01.teste/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', $args );
```

Retorna os artigos mais recentes do site01, o mesmo conteúdo que seria padrão na página principal dele.

Comment: Olá, obrigado por responder.
No caso, em que arquivo eu devo fazer a notificação?

Comment: modificação? ***